# Select width with jeditable

Tags: jquery, select, jeditable, jsfiddle

I have created a Select options with [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/william/mT4XV/) is exactly the case similar to my one.

I need to increase the width of my select options.

How can i achieve that?

This is my code

```
    $('.editable_select').editable(function(value, settings) { 
     console.log(this);
     console.log(value);
     console.log(settings);
     return(value);
  }, {
     data   : "{'example1':'example1','example2':'example2','example3':'example3'}", 
     type    : 'select',
     submit  : 'OK',
     style  : "inherit",
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add following style:

```
#editable select​ { width: 200px }​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mT4XV/45/)

Comment: Thanks i have tried to apply css class like that, i dont know why the width does not increase. I have edited my question to show my code

Comment: It will be in the selector.. Try **.editable_select select { width: 200px }​** or add your html markup please.

Comment: Perfect Michal, applying this CSS now the width has increased. Thanks

Comment: Just one more question, what you mean it's in the selector?

Comment: The CCS selector.. Since you used **class editable_select** and in the fiddle there was **id editable**.

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use the width - method of jquery?

http://api.jquery.com/width/